# How to use MySQL like operator in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following syntax in my code, but it is not working when I am trying to use the `LIKE` operator in JDBC. It works fine in this way, when it is just equal:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * 
                                                FROM drawings 
                                               WHERE name = '"+ DT +"'");
```

But if I want to use the `LIKE` operator to search as a wildcard, I keep getting the error saying that "%" is not a valid character. How I can correctly use the LIKE operator?

Comment: Please don't tell me you are executing queries from your JSP page.

Comment: What does your LIKE query look like?

Comment: query=("SELECT * FROM drawings WHERE name LIKE '"%DT%"'");

Comment: I know it is wrong, but I have tried to search for examples, but I cannot find anything.... I know I should not be executing queries a JSP page, but this is the way programming is done in the company I work for... I do apologise if you consider a bad practice, but I this stage, I just need some help... thanks

Comment: I posted an answer. But once again, this is not a JSP problem. Writing Java/JDBC code in a JSP file instead of a Java class and having problems with Java/JDBC code doesn't make it a JSP problem. So I removed the JSP references/tags from your question. Once you've problems with for example JSP lifecycle, tags and/or EL, then we can speak of a JSP problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the comments:

> ```
> query=("SELECT * FROM drawings WHERE name LIKE '"%DT%"'");
> ```

This does not compile. Assuming that `DT` is a variable, then it should rather look like

```
query = "SELECT * FROM drawings WHERE name LIKE '%" + DT + "%'";
```

*(pay attention to the syntax highlighting, the `%` has to be part of the SQL string!)*

However, concatenating user-controlled string variables like that in a SQL query puts doors *wide* open for successful [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). [Learn](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) how to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and use it instead.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM drawings WHERE name LIKE ?";
// ...
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "%" + DT + "%");
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
// ...
```

Comment: Many thanks Balus... now I understood your comment about the JSP... I would definitely take this into account and avoid using the wrong tags on my questions... many thanks again, your answer solved a problem I had for 2 days, and I am implementing preparedStatement also. Regards